# Yii global variables and setting issue

Tags: yii

I am developing a social networking website using Yii. While frequently using the following things I am having great data manageability issue.
- User ID
- Current user ID (the user which profile is the owner viewing) 
- Is owner???

where can I define these things.
I would something like

```
if(Yii::app()->owner==ME){
//do something
}
// and similarly
if($this->isMyFreind(<Current user ID>){
}
// $this(CanIView()){

}
```

I want these functions to be public for any page? But how?
In other words
**Where can I put my library which contains my own favorite functions like text shortening, image cropping, date time format etc etc??**

Comment: So my answer was deleted by a moderator although it was accepted with 2 upvotes. No reason was given. Time to leave this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MVC model, things like image cropping or date time formats would go in models. You would simply create models for that.

Answer (score 3):

In Yii, you can do achieve this by making a class (under protected/compoents) which inherits

> CApplicationComponent

class. And then you call any property of this class globally as a component.

```
class GlobalDef extends CApplicationComponent {
 public $aglobalvar;
}
```

Define this class in main config under components as:

```
'globaldef' => array('class' => 'application.components.GlobalDef '),
```

And you can call like this:

```
echo Yii::app()->globaldef->aglobalvar;
```

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a globals.php file with all my common functions
In the index.php (yip the one in the root):

```
$globals='protected/globals.php';
require_once($globals);
```

I can then call my global functions anywhere. For example, I shorten certain Yii functions like:

```
function bu($url=null){
    static $baseUrl;
    if ($baseUrl===null)
        $baseUrl=Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;
    return $url===null ? $baseUrl : $baseUrl.'/'.ltrim($url,'/');
}
```

So I can then call the `Yii::app()->request->baseUrl` by simply calling `bu()`

Comment: I think this is not the "Yii way" to store global data